# Laravel artisan doesn't show anything, when wrong mysql credentials

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

When I trying to run migrations, Artisan just didn't anything. No errors, no messages, nothing at all. Empty logs in storage⁩/logs⁩/laravel.log. APP_DEBUG set to 'true'. Using --verbose did not give any effect.

composer update, dump-autoload, clearing laravel caches, configs, compiles etc, have removed all composer packages.. nothing helped.

After 5 days reinstalling and updating of just anything that was on my mac, by poke method I found, that the reason was in using default mysql user root with blank password. When I created user 'admin' with password '12345', set it in .env and run `php artisan config:clear` migrations started to work. Besides artisan that strange silent error was also in the tinker. 
`\DB::table('test')->where('id', 1)->first();` returns just nothing, and execution didn't end, I could watch the cursor blink for minutes, waiting for nothing.

[image]
[image]
*the seventh minute passed, as I looked at it, and wondered where at least the error of 'Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded'* ;(

It’s more important for me to understand not how to avoid this error (that I was already found), but why no messages are displayed.

- os - macOS Mojave 10.14.6;
- php version - 7.4;
- mysql version - 8;
- Laravel Framework version - 6.9.0;
- all installed with homebrew and composer;

Comment: try to check the DB connection in tinker

Comment: same behavior: `DB::connection()->getPdo();` returns nothing, just like on screenshot